# this error 'PYDEVD_DISABLE_FILE_VALIDATION=1'

Tags: python, face-recognition

I just start jupyter notebook and this error come

```
0.00s - Debugger warning: It seems that frozen modules are being used, which may
0.00s - make the debugger miss breakpoints. Please pass -Xfrozen_modules=off
0.00s - to python to disable frozen modules.
0.00s - Note: Debugging will proceed. Set PYDEVD_DISABLE_FILE_VALIDATION=1 to disable this validation.
[I 23:44:39.161 NotebookApp] Kernel started: 00be0898-09b2-4c6a-8e84-565b6e918c96, name: python3
0.00s - Debugger warning: It seems that frozen modules are being used, which may
0.00s - make the debugger miss breakpoints. Please pass -Xfrozen_modules=off
0.01s - to python to disable frozen modules.
0.00s - Note: Debugging will proceed. Set PYDEVD_DISABLE_FILE_VALIDATION=1 to disable this validation.
```

and in jupyter like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cw8gX.png)

before error, i installed `mtcnn`.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)